# Redux action not dispatched. TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my application I want to add a 'ticket' to an array in the 'event' object. In the action I post the new ticket to the database, and after that I dispatch the action to the reducer. By using the Redux logger, I am able to retrieve the error:

[image]

The action of 'createTicket' is this:

```js
// actions/tickets.js

export const TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS = 'TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS';

const ticketCreateSuccess = tickets => ({
  type: TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  tickets
});

export const createTicket = (eventId, data) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const jwt = getState().currentUser.token;
  const id = getState().currentUser.userId;
  const email = getState().currentUser.email;
  const name = getState().currentUser.name;

  request
    .post(`${baseUrl}/events/${eventId}/tickets`)
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`)
    .send(data)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(ticketCreateSuccess({ ...response.body, user: { id, email, name } }));
    })
    .catch(error => error);
};
```

The reducer

```js
// reducers/events.js    

import { EVENT_FETCHED } from '../actions/events';
import { TICKET_EDIT_SUCCESS, TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS } from '../actions/tickets';

export default (state = null, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EVENT_FETCHED:
      return action.event;
    case TICKET_EDIT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        tickets: state.tickets.map(ticket => {
          if (ticket.id === action.ticket.id) {
            return action.ticket;
          }
          return ticket;
        })
      };
    case TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS:
      console.log({ ...state, tickets: [...state.tickets, action.tickets] });
      return { ...state, tickets: [...state.tickets, action.tickets] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The reducers are combined into :

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import currentUser from './currentUser';
import events from './events';
import event from './event';
import ticket from './ticket';
import tickets from './tickets';
import numberOfTickets from './numberOfTickets';

export default combineReducers({ currentUser, events, event, ticket, tickets, numberOfTickets });
```

Comment: What is the format of `response.body` on this line `dispatch(ticketCreateSuccess({ ...response.body, user: { id, email, name } }));`  ?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you're trying to spread your reducer state when its value is `null`:

```
export default (state = null, action = {}) => {
```

```
return {
  ...state, // Here
  // rest
}
```

Your default state should probably be an object, e.g.:

```
const InitialState = {
  tickets: []
};

export default (state = InitialState, action) => {
  // Some code
  case TICKET_CREATE_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      tickets: [
        ...state.tickets,
        action.tickets
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**just add this ...state || []**
and you are good to go.
the problem is value of ...state equals null with empty array and when you try to iterate over null it creates an error.
**so use and "OR" operator and it will work fine.**